# Calling a Method on a Linked List inside of Javascript implementation of a Hash Table

Tags: javascript, methods, linked-list, hashtable

I'm working on creating a Hash Table in Javascript to better understand the data structure. I implemented it with a Linked List at each table position to deal with conflicts.

The problem is that I cannot call .add on this.storage[index], as it is undefined. When I log this.storage[index] I see my head nodes in my linked list and the methods that I need. So I'm not sure what the problem is.

```js
var Node = function(key, value) {
  this.key = key;
  this.value = value;
  this.next = null;
};

var LinkedList = function() {
  this.head = new Node('head');
  this.add = function(key, value) {
    var node = new Node(key, value);
    var curNode = this.head;
    while (curNode.next !== null) {
      curNode = curNode.next;
    }
    curNode.next = node;
  };
  this.find = function(key) {
    var curNode = this.head;
    while (curNode.key !== key && curNode.next !== null) {
      curNode = curNode.next;
    }
    return curNode.value;
  };
};

var HashTable = function(max) {
  this.max = max;
  this.storage = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < max; ++i) {
    this.storage[i] = new LinkedList();
  }
  this.hash = function(key) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < key.length; ++i) {
      sum += key[i].charCodeAt() - 97;
    }
    return sum % this.max;
  };
  this.addValue = function(key, value) {
    var index = this.hash(key);
    this.storage[index].add(key, value);
  };
  this.getValue = function(key) {
    var index = this.hash(key);
    return this.storage[index].find(key);
  };
};

var hash = new HashTable(5);
hash.addValue("I");
hash.addValue("would");
hash.addValue("like");
hash.addValue("coffee");
hash.getValue('I');
```

Comment: Did you check the value of `index`? When I look at it during the error, it's `-4`.

Answer (score 0):

The Javascript modulus operator doesn't work as you might expect for negative numbers. If `sum` is `-4`, `sum % max` is not `max - 4`, it's `-4`. Then you try to add to `this.storage[-4]`, which is undefined. You need to check for this and adjust.

```js
var Node = function(key, value) {
  this.key = key;
  this.value = value;
  this.next = null;
};

var LinkedList = function() {
  this.head = new Node('head');
  this.add = function(key, value) {
    var node = new Node(key, value);
    var curNode = this.head;
    while (curNode.next !== null) {
      curNode = curNode.next;
    }
    curNode.next = node;
  };
  this.find = function(key) {
    var curNode = this.head;
    while (curNode.key !== key && curNode.next !== null) {
      curNode = curNode.next;
    }
    return curNode.value;
  };
};

var HashTable = function(max) {
  this.max = max;
  this.storage = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < max; ++i) {
    this.storage[i] = new LinkedList();
  }
  this.hash = function(key) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < key.length; ++i) {
      sum += key[i].charCodeAt() - 97;
    }
    sum = sum % this.max;
    if (sum < 0) {
        sum = this.max + sum;
    }
    return sum;
  };
  this.addValue = function(key, value) {
    var index = this.hash(key);
    this.storage[index].add(key, value);
  };
  this.getValue = function(key) {
    var index = this.hash(key);
    return this.storage[index].find(key);
  };
};

var hash = new HashTable(5);
hash.addValue("I");
hash.addValue("would");
hash.addValue("like");
hash.addValue("coffee");
hash.getValue('I');
console.log(hash);
```